# C++: Using unique_copy on just one element

Tags: c++

This is the implementation as found on cplusplus.com

```
template <class InputIterator, class OutputIterator>
  OutputIterator unique_copy (InputIterator first, InputIterator last,  
                              OutputIterator result) {
  if (first==last) return result;

  *result = *first;
  while (++first != last) {
    typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type val = *first;
    if (!(*result == val))   // or: if (!pred(*result,val)) for version (2)
      *(++result)=val;
  }
  return ++result;
}
```

So when when "first" and "last" iterators point to the same element, we don't return anything? That seems out-of-line with unique_copy's definition: the first element from every consecutive group of equivalent elements in the range [first,last) is copied. Is it because of the "last)" part? Can anyone clarify? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that the [first, last) is the problem.

When assigning iterators to containers, it is standard that the last iterator you can possible have is to the memory position 1 iteration after the last element in the container.

Ex.

```
vector<int> aVec{5,-8,23,200};
vector<int>::iterator currentItr, lastItr;

// iterator to first element, 5
currentItr = aVec.begin(); 


// iterator to element ***directly after*** last element
lastItr = aVec.end();
// in other words, there is no reason to access the value attached to lastItr
```

One reason why the .end() standard exists is to easily tell when the currentItr has reached past the usable values in a container;

Ex.

```
while (currentItr != lastItr) // currentItr will not print once it's equal to lastItr
    cout << *currentItr++ << endl;
```

In your specific example, if there is one element in a container, then the iterators [first, last) should not be equal.
"first" is an iterator located one element to the left of iterator "last".

If first == last, then the span of possible iterators is:

[first, first)
 or
[last, last)

The possible span cannot *both* **include** *and* **exclude** any iterator.
That sounds crazy.

Good luck.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I was thinking iterators as pointers to say, the vector's element, while vectors' iterators aren't exactly pointers. Such as the vec.end() example. Rookie mistake, thanks for the clarification!